# Can I update my USB stick to a new version without filling it up and ruining the persistent space?

Tags: updates, lubuntu, live-usb

I have a 4GB stick with Lubuntu on it, and 3GB is assigned to persistence. Would I be able to update 12.10 without filling it up and making it useless until I fix it?

Comment: Do you have a proper Lubuntu installation on USB, or is it just a Live USB?